# In android how to check the internet connection at regular intervals

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, androidhttpclient

What i need Precisely is  my code should check internet  status at regular intervals (Say every 30 or 40 seconds ).How to do this ..Should i use Demon thread or any other components available in  android .Hope am clear .

Comment: you can use timer for that...
set timer interval for 30 sec and call function for check internet connection..

Answer (score 1):

try this one to check internet connection availability

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
ConnectivityManager connectivity =   (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (connectivity != null) {
NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
if (info != null)
    for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
        if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Use this one to check every 40 sec

```
Timer  networkTimer = new Timer();
NetWorkTimerTask networkTimerTask = new NetWorkTimerTask();
networkTimer.schedule(networkTimerTask, 0,40*1000);
public class NetWorkTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        networkHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}; 
@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
Handler networkHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        isOnline = isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    }
};
```

Add permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: I make some changes, try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and add this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: This code shows me the status of internet connection like it is true or false.I had already implemented this. what i need is check this internet connection regularly for every 10 or 15 seconds .It should run in back ground checking the net connection regularly ..How to check in back ground regularly..

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo == null || !netInfo.isConnected() || !netInfo.isAvailable()) {
            /*
             * Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Internet connection!",
             * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             */
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and Call it like

```
if (isOnline()) {
//code if net available
}
else
{
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Internet connection available  ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And if you want to check on Interval then put if condition in thread